# Can an iterator such as std::filesystem::directory_iterator be used outside of a loop?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to understand how things like iterators can be used in c++, and would specifically like to understand std::filesystem::directory_iterator better.

I understand the straight forward examples like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

void doSomething(std::string filename)
{
    std::cout << filename;
};

int main()
{
    auto iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator("c:/somefolder");
    for (auto& i : iterator)
    {
        doSomething(std::filesystem::path(i.path()).filename().string());
    }
}
```

But lots of legacy code isn't made in a tight loop like that. Is it possible to use the directory_iterator in a way somewhat similar to WinAPI FindNextFile()?

Something similar to this:

```
std::string getNextFilename(std::string path)
{
    // Notice the actual filesystem access code is neatly packed away in a replaceable function suitable for a HAL.
    static auto iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path);
    return std::filesystem::path(iterator.path()).filename().string();
}

int main()
{
    while (std::string fileName = getNextFilename("c:/somefolder"))
    {
        doSomething(fileName);
    }

    // or

    std::string fileFirst  = getNextFilename("c:/somefolder");
    std::string fileSecond = getNextFilename("c:/somefolder");
    std::string fileLast   = getNextFilename("c:/somefolder");

}
```

Please answer:

1. In general for iterators, can or can't they be used like this, and why?
2. In specific how to perform this sort of directory lookup of one file/directory at a time.

edit1: Clarified title.

Comment: It’s not really clear what you’re asking for. Do you just want to use the filesystem iterator outside the context of a ranged for-loop? Or do you actually require that the iterator be “rebuilt” from the filename each time?

Comment: A range based for loop is essentially just syntax sugar for incrementing an iterator and checking whether it reached an `end()` iterator (see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), so you can always manually replicate such behavior. However there is no `operator bool` for `std::string` so you'd need to structure your `getNextFilename` differently to have an "end" condition (e.g.: return a `std::optional<std::string>`)

Comment: `for (auto& e : range)` can be translated to `for (auto it = std::begin(range), it != std::end(range); ++it)`...

Comment: Basically, I wanted to know if it was possible for it to somehow return the first result, and on subsequent calls return the next results one at a time.

Comment: @UnholySheep Sounds like what I'm thinking of... but how can this actually be implemented?

Comment: @Sneftel Yes, I'd like to use it outside of a ranged for-loop. It should not rebuild or restart before being specifically being asked to do so.

Comment: I would strongly advise against `getNextFilename` having a `static auto iterator = ...`, as you'd now got the situation where `getNextFilename` can only be used to iterate *one* directory, *once* in your entire program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easily possible to manually increment iterators (since that is what the range based `for` loop does as well). However you need to adjust the other code accordingly, as there is no `operator bool` for `std::string`. One possible solution (only slightly modifying the original code, which still includes all its issues) could look like this (using `std::optional<std::string>` to enable returning an "end" condition):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <optional>

void doSomething(std::string filename)
{
    std::cout << filename;
};

std::optional<std::string> getNextFilename(std::string path)
{
    static auto iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path);
    if (iterator != std::filesystem::directory_iterator()) {
        auto filename = std::filesystem::path(iterator->path()).filename().string();
        ++iterator; // advance iterator to next entry in directory
        return filename; // uses implicit constructor of `std::optional`
    } else {
        return {}; // return empty optional if we reached end of directory
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (auto fileName = getNextFilename("c:/somefolder"))
    {
        doSomething(*fileName); // dereference optional to get value
    }

    // or

    auto fileFirst  = getNextFilename("c:/somefolder");
    auto fileSecond = getNextFilename("c:/somefolder");
    auto fileLast   = getNextFilename("c:/somefolder");

}
```

Comment: @Caleth As you correctly pointed out in a comment to my question, the use of `static auto iterator = `  needs some special care, such as adding this to make sure it can be updated:`
 static std::string oldPath;
 if (path.compare(oldPath) != 0) {
  iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path);
  oldPath = path;
 }`
Not so elegant, but understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to have a more or less drop-in replacement for FindFirstFile/FindNextFile, the solution could loook like this:

```
struct HANDLE{
    std::filesystem::directory_iterator it;
};
bool FindNextFile(HANDLE &handle, std::string& output) {
    if(handle.it == std::filesystem::directory_iterator{}) return false;
    output=handle.it->path().string();
    handle.it++;
    return true;
}
HANDLE FindFirstFile(std::string input, std::string& output) {
    HANDLE h;
    h.it=std::filesystem::directory_iterator{input};
    FindNextFile(h,output);
    return h;
}
```

Comment: or just `using HANDLE = std::filesystem::directory_iterator`

Comment: @Caleth Yes, you could do so, good hint. A struct can have the advantage that it can made opaque, but then I would have had returned pointers to the handle.

Comment: You can have an opaque pointer to `std::filesystem::directory_iterator`, it's a class type like any other

Comment: @Caleth Propably. I am not sure about that, because you would need to predeclare std::filesystem::directory_iterator to keep the filesystem header out of the compilation unit. And predeclare a std class seems tricky to me because you do not know their implementation.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very useful suggestion to add to my toolbox.

Answer (score -1):

```
std::filesystem::path my_path("C:/");
for (std::filesystem::directory_iterator itt(my_path);
     itt != std::filesystem::directory_iterator(); itt++)
    {
         const std::filesystem::directory_entry& entr = *itt;
         std::string filename = entr.path().string();
    }
```

Seems there is no `begin()` and `end()` here. also no `--` operator. So seems  impossible for example iterate it from end to begin. also no `size()` function